# Sending Asp.Net email through gmail

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email via GMail from ASP.Net using the code and config below. Unfortunatly it doesn't seem to be working and it also isn't throwing an error message. There is nothing in the server logs or the mail IIS mail folders, I even checked the trash of the from address to see if the mail ended up there.  Any help would be really appreciated.

**C# Section**

```
    public void SendFeedback()
    {
        string emailFrom = this.Email.Text;

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        // here is an important part:
        message.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom, "Mailer");
        // it's superfluous part here since from address is defined in .config file
        // in my example. But since you don't use .config file, you will need it.
        message.Subject = "www.gumpshen.com - Website Query";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = string.Format(" Name = {0}, Phone = {1}", Name.Text, Phone.Text);
        message.Body += Environment.NewLine;
        message.Body += Environment.NewLine;
        message.Body += ProjectDetails.Text; ;

        var client = new SmtpClient();

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
```

**This is the Config section:**

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="myEmail@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network" >
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" 
        userName="myEmail@gmail.com" password="myPassword"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I have it hosted on a Virtual Private Server, it may be something to do with the way I have configured SMTP mail in IIS7 but I just ran the wizard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `client.EnableSsl=true;`

Check the code from this site: [Email via Gmail](https://web.archive.org/web/20130531014149/http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-send-HTML-Email-from-ASP-NET-using-your-Gmail-account.aspx)

> Here is an example on how to send HTML email from your ASP.NET page using your Google account.
>      (This setup can be easily used to send messages via any other SMTP server that requires authentication).
>      Note: the code snippet assumes you have a Label component on Page with named lblMsg that will show
>      success/failure message to the user that is sending email.
>      (But this can be easily changed).
>
> ```
>    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
>    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
>    client.EnableSsl = true;
>    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
>    client.Port = 587;
>
>    // setup Smtp authentication
>    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = 
>        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your_account@gmail.com", "yourpassword");
>    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
>    client.Credentials = credentials;                
>
>    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
>    msg.From = new MailAddress("your_account@gmail.com");
>    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("destination_address@someserver.com"));
>
>    msg.Subject = "This is a test Email subject";
>    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
>    msg.Body = string.Format("<html><head></head><body><b>Test HTML Email</b></body>");
>
>    try
>    {
>        client.Send(msg);
>        lblMsg.Text = "Your message has been successfully sent.";
>    }
>    catch (Exception ex)
>    {
>        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
>        lblMsg.Text = "Error occured while sending your message." + ex.Message;
>    }
> ```

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130531014149/http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-send-HTML-Email-from-ASP-NET-using-your-Gmail-account.aspx not found